# How to remove brackets from lists in list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I'd like to remove the brackets around my querysets using list comprehension.

This is what I have :

```
foo = [[<queryset: two>], [<queryset: four>], [<queryset: one>]]
```

And this is what I want :

```
bar = [<queryset: two>, <queryset: four>, <queryset: one>]
```

I tried to use list comprehension like so but it didn't change anything :

```
bar = [x for x in foo]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `bar = [x[0] for x in foo]` would get it done

Comment: `x == [<queryset>]` `x[0] == <queryset>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
In [1]: foo = [['<queryset: two>'], ['<queryset: four>'], ['<queryset: one>']]
In [2]: [i[0] for i in foo]
Out[2]: ['<queryset: two>', '<queryset: four>', '<queryset: one>']
```